# Can I safely delete all apps data except the current one from my google-services.json file?

Tags: android, firebase

So, the Firebase has a limit on the number of projects on the free plan. When the number of apps which I worked on exceeds them - I had to add several apps to 1 project.

Suppose I have a Firebase project called *Job*. And there are apps called *A*, *B*, *C*. When the customer of *C* app receives the app repository, he can see *A* and *B* apps data in the *google-services.json* file.

Can I delete the data of *A* and *B* from this file so that it doesn't break the normal work of the *C* app and all of it Firebase services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be OK.  google-services.json is **not** just copied entirely into your app.

You'll know it's OK because your app will still build.  The google services gradle plugin just copies the relevant values out of there in to string resources in your app, based on the ID of the app build.

After the app builds, google-services.json is no longer used when the app runs.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you are able to do that. Just try to remove lines correctly.

This sometimes happens when you already added `google-services.json` to your project and add new app package name into Firebase. Then `google-services.json` from Firebase becomes different than your local one. And it still works.